# Passing of John Nash

Tags: discussion

I'm sorry to report the sad news that John Nash has died.
Requiescat in pace.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207477/john-nashs-legacy

Comment: Fate can be cruel but let us thank Her for allowing Nash to collect his Abel prize in May 2015, two months before his death.

Comment: How do you count two months?

Comment: Nash's Abel prize was indeed officially awarded in Oslo on May 19th, but already announced on March 25th by the Norwegian Academy of Sciences and Letters: apologies for inaccurately expressing myself. I meant that it is a consolation that  Nash was permitted to live through both these days.

Comment: But the terribly sad irony is that he was killed in a taxi crash returning from the airport on his way home after the Abel Prize award ceremonies.

Comment: I am very pleased to know that a mathematician did fight mental problems,won the fight and won the Abel prize.This is the best thing to remember from him.Feel happy because he lived.Not sad because he died.